# How can I deploy a PS1 script with a nuget package

Tags: nuget, nuspec

I have a PS1 script that I use in all my projects to sign the assemblies. Until now I copied this file over to all my projects. Now I wanted to create a nuget package with the PS1 file.

I created a nuspec file and put the file in "content". Unfortunately nothing happened. Then I tried to put it in lib. Still noting happened. When I restore the package in my project no files where created in this project.

When I analyst the nupkg file with my 7-Zip the file looks OK. The ps1 file was in content, lib respectively.

I didn't found anything to this topic online. Can someone explain to me, how to create such a NuGet-Package?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When a project using `packages.config` installs a NuGet package, the package's `tools\install.ps1` script will run. However, [this no longer happens when the project using the package uses `PackageReference`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/nuget/reference/migrate-packages-config-to-package-reference#installps1-scripts-are-ignored-when-the-package-is-installed-after-the-migration) (such as SDK style projects, used by .NET Core).

Similarly, the files in the `content` folder of the `nupkg` are copied into the project on install, but [only when the project uses `packages.config`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/nuget/reference/migrate-packages-config-to-package-reference#content-assets-are-not-available-when-the-package-is-installed-after-the-migration). `PackageReference` projects use the `contentFiles` folder in the `nupkg`, however the behaviour is different. Those files are copied only on build, not install, for .NET Framework projects and on publish for .NET Core projects. Probably not what you want for signing assemblies.

The feature you probably want to use is [including MSBuild props and targets in your package](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/nuget/create-packages/creating-a-package#including-msbuild-props-and-targets-in-a-package). Note that the `props` and `targets` file names must match the package id exactly for NuGet to use them. You probably want to use `afterTargets="build"` at a guess.

Comment: Yeah, I found out, that PackageReference has like an attribute that you can use to set a msbuild variable with the path to the NuGet package’s content. I used this in my PostBuild process. – But the solution with the props and targets actually was the even better solution to this problem.